# Where can I find pencil tool in Open Office drawing?

Tags: openoffice.org, tools

In Table menu in MS Word, we have the option to draw a table by using pencil tool and erase the line of the table by using eraser. How can we do the same in Open Office drawing?

Comment: I can not find the pencil tool in Openoffice.org drawing. My system is Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom bar you will see the picture of a pencil with a arrow pointing down, click the arrow.

You will see 6 different icons, choice the last one (counting from left to right, top to down).

The next picture is a screenshoot, showing what you should click. For better understanding.

[image: screenshoot-with-steps]

And this is my result:

[image: result-picture]

Answer (score 1):

I think. You should use Open Office **Writer** as an alternative for MS Word and **Not Open Office Draw** :)

Furthermore, you may find detailed info in its documentation http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got an answer for your query.
The solution is below:

1. Open Open office writer
2. Go to the "Table" drop down menu and select "Insert">> "Table"
3. It will open "Insert Table" window. Please keep the default 2 columns and 2 rows values and click OK.
4. You will see a table being inserted into the writer with 2 columns and 2 rows
5. Now we need the 'Second Row of the First column' to be SPLIT into 2 rows. For that select the it and right click.
6. After you right click, you will see a dropdown menu which contains "Cell" option. Select it "Split" from it.
7. It shows the Split Cells dialog box. Type "2" in Split cells into and Select the direct. Here I want it to be Horizontal.
8. That's it you have got what you want. In fact, you would do the same thing in Ms Word using draw table which we have done using the split cells.